# "Key for add operation must be defined" error on ant fresh_install or ant update

Tags: postgresql, ant, dspace

while installing dspace I get following error:

```
test_database:
 [java] Failure during kernel init: Key for add operation must be defined!
 [java] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key for add operation must be defined!
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.DefaultExpressionEngine.prepareAdd(DefaultExpressionEngine.java:420)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.addPropertyDirect(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:383)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.addPropertyValues(AbstractConfiguration.java:423)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.append(AbstractConfiguration.java:1271)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.convertToHierarchical(ConfigurationUtils.java:252)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration$ConfigData.getTransformedRoot(CombinedConfiguration.java:943)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.constructCombinedNode(CombinedConfiguration.java:793)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.getRootNode(CombinedConfiguration.java:626)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.fetchNodeList(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:958)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.fetchNodeList(CombinedConfiguration.java:739)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.getProperty(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:344)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.setProperty(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:354)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.setDynamicProperties(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:539)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.loadInitialConfig(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:504)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.<init>(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:87)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:148)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
 [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:49)
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure during kernel init: Key for add operation must be defined!
 [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:65)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key for add operation must be defined!
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.DefaultExpressionEngine.prepareAdd(DefaultExpressionEngine.java:420)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.addPropertyDirect(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:383)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.addPropertyValues(AbstractConfiguration.java:423)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.append(AbstractConfiguration.java:1271)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.convertToHierarchical(ConfigurationUtils.java:252)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration$ConfigData.getTransformedRoot(CombinedConfiguration.java:943)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.constructCombinedNode(CombinedConfiguration.java:793)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.getRootNode(CombinedConfiguration.java:626)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.fetchNodeList(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:958)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration.fetchNodeList(CombinedConfiguration.java:739)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration.getProperty(HierarchicalConfiguration.java:344)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.setProperty(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:354)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.setDynamicProperties(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:539)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.loadInitialConfig(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:504)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.<init>(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:87)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:148)
 [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
 [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:49)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/uttam/Desktop/Epub/edoc-dspace-source/dspace/target/dspace-
installer/build.xml:792: Java returned: 1
```

I had a working dspace but after I cleaned dspace database I keep getting this error message. I have tired reinstalling postgresql after clean wipe but I keep getting this error, any suggestion on what might be causing this?

Now, If I want to start from the beginning "mvn package" works but after that "ant fresh_install" throws this error.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I now know what the problem was. This error code is related to config file(.cfg) in the dspace source folder. I had some special characters in my local.cfg file and I somehow managed to overlook that, removing those special characters solved the case.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use dspace 6.0 with these dependencies,

- apache-ant-1.8.0
- apache-maven-3.1.0
- apache-tomcat-7.0.69
- jdk-7u79-windows
- postgresql-9.5.2

  the error occurred then.so i update dspace to 6.3 version then error does not occur.